Advection equation of heat transfer during fluid flow in pipe with heat loss
I am trying to model transient temperature profile during fluid flow in pipe considering heat exchange with the surrounding. I am trying to use overall heat transfer coefficient to model heat exchange to simplify the problem. I would like to check if this the correct implementation of heat exchange term to the advection equation where $U$ is the overall heat transfer coefficient and $r$ is the radius of the pipe.
$$\begin{align*}
\rho C_p\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\rho C_pu\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}&=\dot{q}\\
\rho C_p\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\rho C_pu\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}&=-\frac{2U(T-T_\text{amb})}{r}\end{align*}
$$
Temperature at $x = 0$ is $T_\text{inj}$ and temperature at $t = 0$ is $T_\text{amb}$. I solved the above IBVP using Laplace transformation and I get the following solution:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{T(x,t)-T_\text{amb}}{T_\text{inj}-T_\text{amb}}=H\Bigg(t-\frac{x}{u}\Bigg)e^{-2\frac{U}{\rho C_p ur}x}.\end{align*}
$$
where $H$ is unit step function. I would like to know if this is a proper way to model temperature evolution in this problem. Am I doing anything wrong in modeling heat exchange with the surrounding using overall heat transfer coefficient? There are some information about the problem:

Fluid flow is turbulent.
Pipe diameter is small compared with pipe length.
Difference between injection temperature and initial temperature is few degree Celsius.


So you are assuming a flat template profile?

yes, I am assuming that heat conduction perpendicular to flow direction is negligible.

I hate to tell you that conductor perpendicular to the flow direction dominates.

Is the flow turbulent or laminar?

Have you determined the steady state solution yet?


Am I doing anything wrong in modeling heat exchange with the surrounding using overall heat transfer coefficient?

The overall heat transfer coefficient $U$ (W/m$^2$ K) is defined by the expression below for heat transfer across a system by combined conduction and convection.
$$ \dot{q} = U\ A\ \Delta T$$
where $\dot{q}$ is the heat flow (W), $A$ is the normal area to the heat flow (m$^2$), and $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference across the system. Constructions of $U$ vary when the system has a Cartesian, cylindrical, or spherical geometry as well as when the path contains series and/or parallel thermal resistance components.
The correction therefore to be made is that your term for $U$ must be obtained from its definition $\dot{q} = U\ A\ \Delta T$ applied in cylindrical coordinates to include a) convection from the inside fluid to the pipe, b) conduction across the pipe, and c) convection from the pipe to the surrounding fluid (air).
